# JAVA Nested Type Generic: mix of super and extends

Tags: java, generics

The following is a valid assignment:

```
List<? extends ArrayList<? extends Integer>> l1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

However, for the following ones, I get incompatible types error

```
List<ArrayList<? extends Integer>> l2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
List<? super ArrayList<? extends Integer>> l3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

What is the logic here?

Also, is there any valid construction for `l2` and `l3`? (i.e. by changing the right side of the equation)

Comment: Side note: I think you want to use List (the interface) and not ArrayList (which is a specific implementation of List) in your declarations. Also, if you're at Java 8 or later, you don't need to recall the generic type in the initialisation (use the diamond operator only)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, you are right, however, I wanted to have something that looks valid for the super case i.e. `? super ArrayList`. If I had  `? super List`, then the `ArrayList` on the right side is clearly wrong.

Comment: But what would be the reason to store super classes of ArrayList in the main list? Why wouldn't you simply make a List of List instead of using the super keyword? I hardly see a world where you ask someone to store classes that are super of ArrayList (meaning they implement List) but not ArrayList, I guess you simply want to set the bound to List and then the implementer will decide what to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's inner level generics are invariant.  That means that embedded type parameter must match exactly.  In this case, if you have `? extends Integer` as your inner parameter on the left, it must be on the right also.

```
List<ArrayList<? extends Integer>> l2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Integer>>();
List<? super ArrayList<? extends Integer>> l3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Integer>>();
```

Or you can use the diamond operator.

```
List<ArrayList<? extends Integer>> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<? super ArrayList<? extends Integer>> l3 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just for the clarification, I have pushed the problem to three levels. So, all the levels after the first level are considered inner level (i.e. not only the last/most inside level).

Comment: BTW, why this is not the case about the `extends`. for example: `List<? extends ArrayList<? extends ArrayList<? extends Integer>>> l1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Integer>>>();`

Answer (score 0):

It is a **Wildcards and Subtyping** problem, we can make some simplifications to help us analysing it.

Mark `ArrayList<? extends Integer>` as type **A**,
mark `ArrayList<Integer>` as type **B**,
we can simplify l1,l2,l3 to

```java
List<? extends A> l1 = new ArrayList<B>();
List<A> l2 = new ArrayList<B>();
List<? super A> l3 = new ArrayList<B>();
```

what is the relationship between A and B ? **B is a subtype of A**, So:
For l1 : `ArrayList<B>` is a subtype of `List<? extends A>`,so it's OK.
For l2 : `ArrayList<B>` is not a subtype of `List<A>` (eg : `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>`)
For l3 :`ArrayList<B>` is not a subtype of `List<? super A>` (eg: `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<? super Number>`)

**Q:** Also, is there any valid construction for l2 and l3? (i.e. by changing the right side of the equation)
**A:** just use the diamond operator